# UITextView <NSATSTypesetter: 0x2819a9ec0>: Exception

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm having an issue with setting HTML attributed text in a UITextView.

Basically I am testing with a very simple html text which works in one project but not in a newer project. The HTML string is as below:

```
<table style=\"width:100%\"> <tr> <th>Firstname</th> <th>Lastname</th> <th>Age</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Jill</td> <td>Smith</td> <td>50</td> </tr> <tr>
```

I set this string to the attributedText value as follows:

```
textView.attributedText =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
 initWithData: [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]
 options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
 documentAttributes: nil
 error: &err];
```

On one project this displays perfectly as I'd expect whereas on a new project I just get a blank TextView with the following error:

```
    <NSATSTypesetter: 0x2819a9ec0>: Exception *** -[NSConcreteTextStorage attribute:atIndex:effectiveRange:]: Range or index out of bounds raised during typesetting layout manager <NSLayoutManager: 0x2810a1000>
    1 containers, text backing has 38 characters
    Currently holding 38 glyphs.
    Glyph tree contents:  38 characters, 38 glyphs, 3 nodes, 192 node bytes, 128 storage bytes, 320 total bytes, 8.42 bytes per character, 8.42 bytes per glyph
    Layout tree contents:  38 characters, 38 glyphs, 1 laid glyphs, 1 laid line fragments, 3 nodes, 192 node bytes, 1712 storage bytes, 1904 total bytes, 50.11 bytes per character, 50.11 bytes per glyph, 1.00 laid glyphs per laid line fragment, 1904.00 bytes per laid line fragment
, glyph range {0 9}. Ignoring...
```

If anybody has ideas why this may be happening it would be much appreciated as I am at a loss with this now as I can't see any difference in setup between the two projects.

Thanks

Comment: Previously (but can't find it now) it was stated that `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute`accepted only UTF8 encoding, it might be linked.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML seems to be fine, i can turn it into `NSAttributedString` with no issue, I am using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` which works fine in most of the cases:

```
NSString *html = @"<table style=\"width:100%\"> <tr> <th>Firstname</th> <th>Lastname</th> <th>Age</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Jill</td> <td>Smith</td> <td>50</td> </tr> <tr>";

NSData *data = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData: data
                                                  options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                       documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Also tested successfully in a Swift playground.

Here is the result

[image]

Swift playground below:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

extension NSAttributedString {

    convenience init(html: String) throws {
        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any] = [
            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]
        let data = html.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        try self.init(data: data ?? Data(html.utf8), options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
    }

}

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 500))
textView.attributedText = try? NSAttributedString(html: "<table style=\"width:100%\"> <tr> <th>Firstname</th> <th>Lastname</th> <th>Age</th> </tr> <tr> <td>Jill</td> <td>Smith</td> <td>50</td> </tr> <tr>")

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = textView
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've amended the options as per your suggestion and it's still not working. I've tried exactly the same in a third app and it also seems fine so I am at a loss why it doesn't work in the intended project yet it works in all the other projects I have tried in. Do you know if there is anything I may be missing?

Comment: I've done some more research into this and it seems to be a library that I use - DTCoreText - even though I don't call anything to do with this library it seems to be still intercepting and causing this issue. 

I will update this if I find a fix.